# My questions is about a file created in the command line not appearing in the project directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rubygems, rails-activerecord

I am currently building a ruby-on-rails app and attempted to create a migration through the command line by using:

`rails g migration create_users username:string email:string password_digest:string --no-test-framework`

The command line says that it successfully creates the migration and gives me the file name, which is `db/migrate/20180907182240_create_users.rb`. **The problem is, it isn't showing up in my project directory on Atom.** I restarted Atom and that didn't seem to do the trick.

I've also tried checking my `git status` and it comes up blank. There are no new files to commit, which leads me to believe that they may not be getting created to begin with.

If someone could help me find the files and/or if someone knows what is going wrong, I'd really appreciate the help! Thank you.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.1'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: You should be able to easily check if the file is there. From where you ran the `rails g migration ...` command just type `ls db/migrate`. The migration file should be listed.

Comment: Maybe you have something wrong on your `.gitignore` file?

Comment: I decided to restart my computer out of frustration and tried once more. It worked! The files were never created to begin with. Who knows why, oh well.